# Use WMI to detect a USB drive was connected, regardless of whether it was mounted?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, wmi

I am writing a script that uses [MS KB 823732](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823732) to temporarily prevent users from plugging in new USB storage devices. This works fine, and the `HKLM\...\Services\UsbStor` registry key successfully blocks newly-connected devices from being accessed.

**Is there a WMI event that will tell me that a drive was *connected*, regardless of whether it was mounted?**

I tried querying for `__InstanceCreationEvent` but that is apparently raised only after the drive is mounted and made available, which doesn't fit my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

.NET version: http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/basharkokash/archive/2008/02/06/usb-port-insert-remove-detection-using-wmi.aspx

With the source: dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/basharkokash/archive/2008/03/15/USB-Detection-source-code.aspx

Relevant section:

```
static void AddInsetUSBHandler()
{

    WqlEventQuery q;
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
    scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

    try
    {

        q = new WqlEventQuery();
        q.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
        q.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        q.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";
        w = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
        w.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(USBAdded);
        w.Start();

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
        if (w != null)
              w.Stop();

    }

}
```